# Navigating& providing directions to a user's GPS location

Tags: android, gps

I've read Google's API policy on Location Services & Maps API, they do not allow one to make an app that provides directions to a user's location. I however wish to make such an app. I know I need to use a third party Maps API, but im unsure if this sort of app would be allowed on the play store.

I've searched extensively. The only references to this not being allowed in the the Maps API terms of service, but no where else. +

The idea is simple, one person sends a request to another, and they track each other with directions provided to find them.

Revalent reddit post by myself. 
http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2qcm22/would_i_get_in_trouble_w_googles_policys_if_i/

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand that it is difficult , you can use Google maps , first try to get another exact coordinates of latitude and longitude , and put them on a Google map , then make getting location via [satellite](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code).